# tempus-dominus doesn't detect moment import

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I know that there's a bunch of question about `moment` and `tempudominus-bootstrap-4` but most of the time it is linked to a user mistake and I didn't find reference of mine ...

So I'm using `symfony` framework and the `webpack-encore` bundle. I want to add tempusdominus to my file `event.js` to use dateTimePicker

```js
//../assets/js/app.js

import $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';
import moment from 'moment';
import 'tempusdominus-bootstrap-4';

$(function () {
    //some datepicker
});
```

when I refresh my page I get the following error

> Error: Tempus Dominus Bootstrap4's requires moment.js. Moment.js must be included before Tempus Dominus Bootstrap4's JavaScript.

from here

```js
// ../tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.js

if (typeof moment === 'undefined') {
  throw new Error('Tempus Dominus Bootstrap4\'s requires moment.js. Moment.js must be included before Tempus Dominus Bootstrap4\'s JavaScript.');
}
```

So apparently my moment variable is undifined. I change my app.js file to render moment in the console

```js
//../assets/js/app.js

import $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';
import moment from 'moment';
//import 'tempusdominus-bootstrap-4';

$(function () {
   console.log("type of moment = "+ typeof(moment));
});
```

to get the following answer :

> type of moment = function

`moment` IS defined, so why tempusDominus doesn't detect it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer came from the github repo [here](https://github.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/issues/293#issuecomment-562353123)

I copy the message here :

You import the `moment` module in a JS file which is bundled by webpack.
Your imported `moment` instance is available at runtime (that's why you can `console.log` it), but is not globally available for non-module libraries (such as `tempusdominus`) relying on global objects to use it.

Using `@symfony/webpack-encore`, you can easily provide a global variable using Encore's `.autoProvideVariables()` method:

```php
Encore
    .autoProvideVariables({
        // Update those to your needs
        $: 'jquery',
        moment: 'moment'
    })
;
```

[More informations in the Doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/legacy-applications.html)